# Reactive Programming style on legacy Databases

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux, project-reactor

With Spring Boot 2, is it possible to code in a reactive style (Mono, Flux and their operators) but keep the JDBC thread pool system?

The goal is to switch to R2DBC drivers when they will be ok for production without changing the controllers et services layers.

Thanks a lot!

Saveriu

Answer (score 0):

The common way to solve that is to wrap those synchronous return types with `Mono` and schedule that work on a specific `Scheduler`. Since this work involves mostly blocking I/O, the `Scheduler.elastic()` is the best choice here.

You can wrap the blocking type with `Mono.fromCallable`, `Mono.fromSupplier`, `Mono.fromFuture` depending on the return type you're getting from the blocking API. You can also use `Mono.fromRunnable` if you just want to know when the task is done and get an empty value.

Check out [the Reactor reference documentation about this](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking).

Note that by doing that, you'll be scheduling work on a thread pool and losing part of the runtime benefits behind non-blocking I/O. Another migration path to consider is to continue using Spring MVC ([which supports reactive return types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async-reactive-types)) and use reactive types where you can. You'll be able to use reactive types where you can and you won't need to wrap things everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I applied the tutorial that you showed at the 2016 belgium devoxx for the bloking directory (youtu.be/Cj4foJzPF80?t=4807) that works but indeed, It's not ideal. The thing is that I don't want to delete good reactive code...

Answer (score 0):

I think the question you asking a bit not accurate. What is the **legacy** databases? As you mentioned JDBC, I will explain my point about SQL databases and reactive programming.

All of SQL databases I know, give you **transactions** mechanism, so when you write to few tables and got error at some step your tables are left clean. What would you do if you will call this few tables insertions in reactive way? Instead of rollback transaction you have to write some code to delete all inserted data. As it seems for me at beginning of 2019 year, it is still hard to apply reactive programming model for SQL databases. So if your domain rely on transactions just hold on with reactive.

Well if you **have to** be reactive with JDBC... I would rather run my reactive stuff in one thread while JDBC application in other thread pool or even in other application.

Reactive have great space to apply, but should be used properly.

Comment: Hi, the goal is not to be reactive but to write a reactive code style (functionnal, Mono, ect.) and keeping a ThreadPool architecture. 

The DB will be changed in the near future and will be reactive capable. 
When it will be done, I don't want to change all the code produced by the team just some months ago, just the minimum (JpaRepo to CassandraReactiveRepo for example).

Comment: When DB will be changed you will get different API. Are you sure you can know the future?

Comment: I'm not agree, when the DB will be changed all the API will remain the same expect some new functionnalities. 
I'm in charge of the APIs of my company.